# How can I approximately solve a 2-player zero-sum game by subselecting its rows/columns?

Tags: approximation, game-theory, nash-equilibrium, algorithmic-game-theory, sparse-matrices

This is rather an open-ended question, but I'm posting here since I was not able to find a good resource elsewhere.

Say there's a two player zero sum game with payoff matrix $A$ that's $N \times H$. Call the value of this game $\lambda_N^*$. If $N$ is very large, we would be interested in finding $n\ll N$ *somehow* that might not do as well, but reasonably approximates $\lambda_N^*$. Let the value of the game of this subpayoff matrix be $\lambda_n^*$.

Here are my questions:

1. Has there been any research on how to wisely select $n$, so that $\lambda_n^*$ best approximates $\lambda_N^*$?
2. If so, can you provide a reference, and the main result, e.g. the approximation ratio, any assumptions necessary for the payoff matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small support strategy profiles that achieve additively approximate Nash equilibria have been studied in both zero-sum games:

Lipton RJ, Young NE. Simple strategies for large zero-sum games with applications to complexity theory. InProceedings of the twenty-sixth annual ACM symposium on Theory of computing 1994 May 23 (pp. 734-740). ACM.

Althöfer I. On sparse approximations to randomized strategies and convex combinations. Linear Algebra and its Applications. 1994 Mar 1;199:339-55.

And, more recently, in general games:

Lipton RJ, Markakis E, Mehta A. Playing large games using simple strategies. InProceedings of the 4th ACM conference on Electronic commerce 2003 Jun 9 (pp. 36-41). ACM.

For an $n \times n$ game and a given $\epsilon$, one can find by brute force search over strategies that are uniform on multisets of pure strategies of size $\log n$ an approximate Nash equilibrium where no player can gain more than $\epsilon$ by deviating in time $n^{\frac{\log n}{\epsilon^2}}$.

Comment: These are all highly relevant papers, thanks. A couple of questions however: are there results that 1) do not sample strategies uniformly at random but be more *clever* about it? And 2) we fix $n$ first and sample, instead of assuming randomness and showing how small $n$ can be to approximate $\lambda_N^*$ well?

Comment: @alpaca Note: one is not sampling uniformly over sets, but over multisets. The LMM result above shows that every NE is well approximated in payoff by "small" supports (at most the number of samples but maybe much less) - the sampling at random is just a proof technique which then applies the probabilistic method. For a zero-sum game, one can find an exact equilibrium in polynomial time, and then one can approximate it with small supports. Of course you may not want to solve the full game - that's fine. Find *any* eps-NE and then you can find a small support approximation to it.

Comment: @alpaca Don't quite follow question 2.

Comment: You answered my question :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, I'm glad.

Comment: I have a follow-up question. Can we find a specific subset of strategies that achieves the best bound without brute force searching over the set of all possible mixed strategies?